# Dynamic Memory Allocation for a 2D Array of Structures in C

Tags: c

I'm diving into a C programming project, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock when it comes to dynamically allocating memory for a 2D array of structures. I'm working with structures that have multiple pieces of data, and I need the array size to be determined at runtime.

Could someone break it down for me in simpler terms or provide an example? I'm struggling to grasp the concept, and any guidance on how to allocate memory dynamically and, importantly, how to free it up when I'm done would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks a bunch for any help or examples you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

There are different data structures that people commonly call 2D arrays of objects:

- an object defined as `type name[rows][cols]` which is allocated statically (*in the data segment*) if defined at the global scope or with a `static` storage class. The dimensions must be constant integer expressions known at compile time, or allocated automatically (*on the stack*) at the local scope, with dimensions that do not need to be constant expressions if the compiler supports variable length arrays introduced in C99.
- an object allocated dynamically from the heap defined as

  ```
  type (*name)[cols] = calloc(sizeof(*name) * rows);
  ```

  here `rows` can be computed at run time and `cols` can also be computed at run time if VLAs are supported.
- an object defined as `type **name` and initialized to point to an array of `rows` pointers to `type` objects, each initialized to point to an array of `cols` `type` objects.  These individual rows may be allocated separately or be chunks of a larger array (of length `rows * cols`) allocated with a single call, or any combination thereof.

For all of the above constructions, you can use `name[row][col]` to access the element at the corresponding coordinates for reading and writing.  Furthermore, `name[row]` evaluates to a pointer to an array of `cols` `type` objects you can pass to functions operating on individual rows (the argument must be declared as `type *row` or `type row[]` or `type row[COLS]`... these declarations are equivalent).

The memory layout for these constructions is quite different and if you pass the array to a function, the corresponding argument must be declared with the proper syntax.

In all cases, it is preferable to use type `size_t` for the dimension sizes and index variables to avoid type conversions and possible integer overflow with computing expressions such as `height * width` or `height * width * sizeof(type)`.

Here are some examples:

Classic C89 flat 2D array with size known at compile time:

```
typedef struct { unsigned char red, green, blue, alpha; } pixel;

void clear_screen(pixel s[480][640]) {
    pixel = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    for (size_t y = 0; y < 480, y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < 480, x++) {
            s[y][x] = pixel;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    pixel screen[480][640];
    clear_screen(screen);
    return 0;
}
```

Classic C89 flat 2D array allocated at run time with all but the first dimensions known at compile time:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { unsigned char red, green, blue, alpha; } pixel;

void clear_screen(size_t height, pixel s[][640]) {  // equivalent: pixel (*s)[640]
    pixel = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    for (size_t y = 0; y < height, y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < 480, x++) {
            s[y][x] = pixel;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *s = getenv("HEIGHT");
    size_t height = s ? atoi(s) : 480;
    pixel (*screen)[640] = calloc(sizeof(*screen), height);
    clear_screen(height, screen);
    free(screen);
    return 0;
}
```

`screen` could also be allocated as an uninitialized 2D array as:

```
    pixel (*screen)[640] = malloc(sizeof(pixel) * height * 640);
```

C99 flat 2D array allocated at run time with dimensions known at run time (assuming VLA support):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { unsigned char red, green, blue, alpha; } pixel;

void clear_screen(size_t width, size_t height, pixel s[height][width]) {  // equivalent: pixel (*s)[width]
    pixel = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    for (size_t y = 0; y < height, y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < width, x++) {
            s[y][x] = pixel;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *s1 = getenv("HEIGHT");
    char *s2 = getenv("WIDTH");
    size_t height = s1 ? atoi(s) : 480;
    size_t width = s2 ? atoi(s) : 640;
    pixel (*screen)[width] = calloc(sizeof(*screen), height);
    clear_screen(width, height, screen);
    free(screen);
    return 0;
}
```

`screen` could also be allocated as an uninitialized 2D array as:

```
    pixel (*screen)[width] = malloc(sizeof(pixel) * height * width);
```

or possibly more readable:

```
    pixel (*screen)[width] = malloc(sizeof(pixel[height][width]));
```

or the less error prone:

```
    pixel (*screen)[width] = malloc(sizeof(*screen) * height);
```

The indirect approach works the same for all version of C and does not require VLA support:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { unsigned char red, green, blue, alpha; } pixel;

void clear_screen(size_t width, size_t height, pixel **s) {
    pixel = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    for (size_t y = 0; y < height, y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < width, x++) {
            s[y][x] = pixel;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *s1 = getenv("HEIGHT");
    char *s2 = getenv("WIDTH");
    size_t height = s1 ? atoi(s1) : 480;
    size_t width = s2 ? atoi(s2) : 640;
    pixel **screen = calloc(sizeof(*screen), height);
    size_t row;
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        screen[row] = calloc(sizeof(**screen), width);
    }
    clear_screen(width, height, screen);
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        free(screen[row]);
    }
    free(screen);
    return 0;
}
```

To minimize the number of allocations and simplify the deallocation process, here is a version where the pixels are allocated as a single array and mapped for access as an indirect 2D array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { unsigned char red, green, blue, alpha; } pixel;

void clear_screen(size_t width, size_t height, pixel **s) {
    pixel = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    for (size_t y = 0; y < height, y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < width, x++) {
            s[y][x] = pixel;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *s1 = getenv("HEIGHT");
    char *s2 = getenv("WIDTH");
    size_t height = s1 ? atoi(s1) : 480;
    size_t width = s2 ? atoi(s2) : 640;
    pixel **screen = calloc(sizeof(*screen), height);
    pixel *pixels = calloc(sizeof(*pixels), height * width);
    size_t row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        screen[row] = pixels + row * width;
    }
    clear_screen(width, height, screen);
    free(pixels);
    free(screen);
    return 0;
}
```